# Bootstrap Form not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, validation, form-submit

I am not very good with PHP or JS, and though I can't code from scratch, I sure can read & understand both. So I created this form on Bootstrap v.4.5.2. The form looks pretty with its inbuilt validation. But I am finding it difficult to get the form to work. When I submit the form, Bootstrap does validate it but it won't proceed. Here is an image of how it appears.

[image]

And here is the script that I am using currently. I picked up the PHP & JS from another website I had developed sometime ago.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate role="form">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_name" name="c_name" placeholder="John Doe" required>
                                <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your full name</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="email">Email id</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="c_email" name="c_email" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" required>
                                <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your email id</div>
                            </div>  
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="c_message" name="c_message" placeholder="Enter your message here..." rows="3" required></textarea>
                                <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter your message</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcW4goTAAAAAJdqW6csCcW7CBSvY2u55dZj8Tb5"></div>
                        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
                    </form><div class="ajax-response"></div>
```

**JS**

```
(function($){

    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var patter= new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };

    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var c_name = $("#c_name").val();
        var c_email = $("#c_email").val();
        var c_message = $("#c_message ").val();
        var responseMessage = $('.ajax-response');

        if (( c_name== "" || c_email == "" || c_message == "") || (!isValidEmailAddress(c_email) )) {
            responseMessage.fadeIn(500);
            responseMessage.html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Check all fields.');
        }

        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "assets/php/mail.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    c_email: c_email,
                    c_name: c_name,
                    c_message: c_message
                },
                beforeSend: function(result) {
                    $('#contact-form button').empty();
                    $('#contact-form button').append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result.sendstatus == 1) {
                        responseMessage.html(result.message);
                        responseMessage.fadeIn(500);
                        $('#contact-form').fadeOut(500);
                    } else {
                        $('#contact-form button').empty();
                        $('#contact-form button').append('<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> Try again.');
                        responseMessage.html(result.message);
                        responseMessage.fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
$to = 'abc@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Mail from ABC';   
extract( $_POST );
if( isset( $c_name ) && isset( $c_email ) && isset( $c_message ) ) {

    $email = filter_var( $c_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );

    if( $email === FALSE ) {
        echo 'Invalid email id...';
        exit( 1 );
    } 
    else {
        $name = $c_name;
        $from = $c_email;

        $message = str_replace( "\n.", "\n..", $c_message );

        $subject = str_ireplace( array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D') , '', stripslashes($subject) ); 

        if( mail( $to, $subject, $message, $from ) ) {
            $result = array(
                'message' => 'Thank you for contacting us!',
                'sendstatus' => 1
            );
            echo json_encode( $result );
        } 
        else {
            $result = array(
                'message' => 'Sorry, something is wrong',
                'sendstatus' => 1
            );
            echo json_encode( $result );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where does it fail? Have you checked the console for errors? Have you checked the network tab to see if it makes a request, what data it sends and what the response is?

Comment: I would also recommend against using `extract()` since that can lead to security issues if you're not careful. In this case, if anyone posts some data that also contains `to` and `subject`, then `extract()` will overwrite your `$to` and `$subject` variables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Quite honestly since I am not good with JS or PHP, my debugging steps have been limited. I only made sure that all the arguments looked valid. I also check the console tab to see if there was any JS errors, but it looks clean. This is the website in question - https://www.walnut.media/